# htaccess rewrite URLby removing #!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL as below,

```
http://localhost:8080/mysite/#!/skin-conditions/angioedema
```

I want this URL to be redirected to

```
http://localhost:8080/mysitenew/?id=skin-conditions/angioedema
```

In here, I want redirected URL to have `mysitenew` instead of `mysitenew` and I want the rest of the URL (after `#!`) to be sent as a parameter. How should I write a rewrite rule for this? I don't want a rewrite condition for this, I just want a rewrite rule.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is not possible: the anchor (or fragment) part of an URL (`#!/skin-conditions/angioedema` in your example) is not sent by the client to the server (no way to rewrite something you don't have).